# For what complex values of $\alpha$ is $f_\alpha$ one to one?

Tags: complex-analysis

We wish to find all complex numbers $\alpha$ such that 
$$f_\alpha(z)=\frac{z}{1+\alpha z^2}$$
is one to one **on the unit disk**. For these values of $\alpha$, find the image of the unit disk under $f_\alpha$.

One calculation shows that if $f(w)=f(z)$ and $w\neq z$ then 
$$ \frac{z}{1+\alpha z^2}=\frac{w}{1+\alpha w^2}\iff 
\alpha(zw^2-z^2w)=(w-z)\iff \alpha wz=1.$$

Is that helpful?

Comment: The image of the unit disk is not defined for all $\alpha$, e.g., for $\alpha=i$ is $f(1)=\infty$.

Comment: Isn't $$\frac{z}{1+\alpha z^\color{red}{2}}$$

Comment: yes it is, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since $|\alpha zw|<|\alpha|\leq1$ on the unit disk. Alternaivie way is using **de Brange's theorem**, 
$$f_\alpha(z)=\frac{z}{1+\alpha z^2}=z-\alpha z^3+\alpha^2z^5-\alpha^3z^7+\cdots$$
then $|\alpha|^n<2n+1$ for all $n$ shows $|\alpha|<\sqrt[n]{2n+1}\to1$.

Comment: $|\alpha| = 1$ is possible, and that must already hold in order for $f$ to be holomorphic  in the unit disk. – Bieberbach's (aka de Brange's) theorem *assumes* that $f$ is injective, I am not sure if that really that helps here.

Comment: thank you.......

Comment: @MartinR If we want to specify the range of $\alpha$, so we should assume that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Bieberbach shows that  if $f$ is injective then $|\alpha|<\sqrt[n]{2n+1}$ for all $n$, in the limit it follows that $|\alpha| \le 1$. But that follows already from the fact that $f$ is holomorphic in the unit disk.

Comment: In other words: $f$ is *defined* only for $|\alpha| \le 1$, and for those $\alpha$ it is injective (as OP's calculation shows). No need to use Bieberbach.